# Using Drupal 8 hook_css_alter to remove core css

Tags: drupal, theming

I've been to remove a specific external css using drupal `hook_css_alter` but I cannot seem to make it work by any means. The stylesheet I'm trying to remove is `contextual.module.css` which is located in the core of drupal 8 stable theme folder

[image]

[image]

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {

    // Remove defaults.css file.
    unset($css[drupal_get_path('themes', 'stable') . '/css/contextual/contextual.module.css']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use libraries-override to avoid stable theme CSS files

```
libraries-override:
  system/base: false
```

Comment: But this syntax won't omit/eliminate everything right?